# The use of や and sentence meaning

Tags: usage, particles, sentence, particle-や

まつさんはラーメンやのうしろの公園に行きます。

In the previous sentence, what is the purpose of the や after ラーメン?

I'm also unsure if the sentence is saying that **"Matsu went to the park behind the ramen shop."** or **"Matsu went to the ramen shop and the park behind it."**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The や here isn't the particle, it's 屋, which means "shop", and is very commonly used as a suffix to words to represent places that sell exclusively, or mainly, that thing. So ラーメン屋 is the ramen store, just like 本屋 is a bookstore, and サイゼリヤ is the place where you buy saizeri (actually that last one's not true).